# How to not superimpose too margin of too div?

Tags: html, css

I want to disconnect the margin of my too div, because the margin bottom of the first div superimpose with the margin top of the second div:

HTML:

```
<div>This element has a margin of 70px.</div>
<div>This element has a margin of 70px.</div>
```

css:

```
div {
  margin: 70px;
  border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
}
```

Comment: use like : margin: 0px 70px 70px 70px;

Comment: I want 70px margin top for the first div too

Comment: margin: 70px 70px 0px 70px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Wrap all the elements in a container. Then instead of using margin on every single element you can use `padding` and `gap`. note, that `gap` is useable for flexbox and grid.

```css
:root {
  --margin: 70px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: var(--margin);
  gap: var(--margin);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>This element has a margin of 70px.</div>
  <div>This element has a margin of 70px.</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can also use the `:first-of-type` selector:

```css
div {
  margin: 0 70px 70px;
}

div:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div>This element has a margin of 70px.</div>
<div>This element has a margin of 70px.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add margin-top only for the first div

```css
div {
  margin: 0px 70px 70px;
  border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
}

div:first-child{
  margin-top:70px;
}
```

```html
<div>This element has a margin of 70px.</div>
<div>This element has a margin of 70px.</div>
```